# Does asp.net membership really provide a secure and robust solution for login, authentication, authorization of web applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I heard that the hashing algorithm for asp.net membership is sha-1, but I've seen in most articles that it is no longer safe, also I would like to know if most professional developers are using asp.net membership or do they come up with their own solution/ implementation with regards to login, authentication, authorization of their system/projects.

Does asp.net membership really provide a secure and robust solution for login, authentication, authorization of web applications? :)

The reason why I'm asking is I would like to know if developers are really using it in their projects.

Sir/Ma'am, Your answers would be of great help.

Comment: This is a conversation that gets skated around a lot but doesn't get enough attention. Good job putting it out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am writing internal applications with a modest number of users then I usually rely on asp.net memberhsip. Its familiar, I know how to get it up and running quickly. Other developers also know it reasonably well so it doesn't need explaining. Its also usually desirable for the organisation to be in control of user accounts.

On the other hand, if you were creating a public site and needed to authenticate users before making contributions (eg. stack overflow), you might want to think about implementing [OpenId](http://openid.net/) so users don't have to create a new account with your domain. They could use Google/Facebook/Twitter instead. There are [libraries](http://nuget.org/packages?q=openid) to get you started.

Comment: Just a word on that - I am not even sure if Google/Facebook/Twitter or Live support OpenID but they all support OAuth2 for sure.

Comment: +1 Nick. I'm developing a site where I'm using .NET Membership but do want a more robust solution. @WiktorZychla, Please expand on OAuth2. Even Better post your own answer. I'd like to know more of your thoughts.

Comment: @DaveA: OAuth2 is built into .net 4.5, it is just as simple as creating a new web app in vs and uncommenting selected providers.

Comment: @DaveA OAuth2 is pretty easy to implement in .NET 4.5, and you can create/use your own custom providers fairly easily. e.g. I was able to create a "login with GitHub" option without many problems. But the "big" providers are packaged.

Answer (score 3):

The [`default hash algorithm`](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770148) changed in .NET 4.0 to SHA256. So you are pretty safe if you are using .NET 4.0.

You could also specify the hash algorithm in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validation="SHA256" />
    <membership defaultProvider="myMembership" hashAlgorithmType="SHA256">
    ...
</system.web>
```

Actually that's was a breaking change in .NET 4.0. So if you had an existing application in .NET 3.5 and upgraded to .NET 4.0 passwords that were hashed with SHA1 might no longer be used in .NET 4.0 unless you change the algorithm type back to SHA1.

Comment: like the perspective. Could you expand on it in your answer? I'm deciding on a provider for a new project. I have a little information on OpenID and OAth2 but would love more perspective on people's experiences.

Comment: @DaveA, what kind of expansion do you need more specifically? The question here was whether the Membership Provider built-in ASP.NET is secure enough. There was a concern about it using the SHA1 algorithm to hash the passwords which is considered not strong enough. I think I have addressed this part in my answer. The Membership Provider in .NET 4 uses SHA256 which should be secure enough. I don't see what does OpenID and OAuth2 has anything to do with the question being asked here. Don't hesitate to formulate another question specifically on the topics you are interested in.

Comment: you covered pretty well that .Net Membership is secure. I was wondering if you had any experience or perspective on pros vs cons of OpenID, OAth2, and SimpleMembership. I feel like this is a conversation worth having.

Comment: yeah I was wondering if this should be its own question. But stack isn't a tolerant place for open ended questions.

Comment: @DaveA, this has absolutely nothing to do with the specific question being asked here. If you want to participate in some discussions I am afraid that StackOverflow is not the right place for this. Quote from the [`FAQ`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): `If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`. If on the other hand you can formulate a specific question do so please but do not hijack other threads for that.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. ASP.NET membership provider is a design failure.

1. It forces you to use predefined domain model entities instead of
   using your own.
2. Not interchangeable with ease (Use different providers per company or different forms of authentication)
3. The predefined MembershipProvider abstraction is a failed class design.(out param ? - yes, please test it)

Go implement your own provider.
For passwords choose your hash algorithm (sha1, sha512...).

After finishing the implementation use FormsAuthentication class to integrate it with your provider.

Comment: there is much to be said for your answer. I've found more I like than not, but if you expand on what you found to be a failure, your experiences developing a better solution, and advice to the OP on how to develop a better solution, I'll happily up your score. More needs to be said on this.

Comment: Hmmm... Lets start:
- It forces me to use predefined domain model entities instead of using my own.
- Not interchangeable with ease (Use different providers per company or different forms of authentication)
- The predefined MembershipProvider abstraction is a failed class design.(out param ? - yes, please test it)